# How can I redirect an address starting with #!

Tags: redirect

I have a new wordpress site instead of my old Wix one.
in the old one there were page addresses like http://example.com/#!contact/ct07/ in the new one this page resides under http://example.com/contact

I've tried 3 redirections plugins but none works (Redirection, redirection editor, quick 301 redirect).

I have no access to the .htaccess file
On redirection it seems like the engine does not see the URL.
Any manageable idea besides JS ? I don't want to miss google juice

Comment: You have to do this in JavaScript. The hash and anything after is not part of the request URI, just used internally by the user agent. .htaccess or PHP never see this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't send the part after `#` to the server, so the server don't know about this part and won't be able to do the redirect.

So you have to do the redirection in javascript:

```
if (/^#contact\//.test(document.location.hash)) {
    document.location = '/contact';
}
```

For SEO purpose, you may want to handle the [`_escaped_fragment_`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174993) parameter too

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a few weeks ago.

PHP does not get anything after hash tag, so it is not possible to parse request url and get hash. But JavaScript can.

Below you find my solution for WordPress redirects by hashtag #! :
(You should put this code in functions.php of your active theme):

```
function themee_hash_redirects() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function themee_hashtag_redirect( hashtag, url) {
            var locationHash = document.location.hash;
            if ( locationHash.match(/#!/img) ) {
                if ( hashtag == locationHash ) {
                    document.location.href = url;
                }
            }
        }
        // Examples how to use themee_hashtag_redirect
        themee_hashtag_redirect('#!contact', '/qqq/');
        themee_hashtag_redirect('#!zzz', '/aaa/');
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'themee_hash_redirects');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.